# Is there a way to call BugreportManager’s hidden functions

Tags: android, hidden-field, bug-reporting

How can we call startBugreport(), I’m designing a system app and I need an api which can trigger bugreports on some system events, is there any way to achieve the same without executing adb commands??

I’ve tried adding necessary permissions for the function call and system app requirements like shareduserid, but not able to find an api to generate the bug report without executing adb shell commands.